# response.ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel" resizing spreadsheet columns width

Tags: asp-classic, excel, vba

Opening an excel spreadsheet with the response object and I am curious to know if there is a way, once all the data has been written to resize/format the columns widths so that all the data fits?

Thanks, Ron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean, set a response header and then throw HTML to the client browser?
MS Excel can handle HTML, but you can't store a VBA macro inside HTML, so there is no simply way to achieve this.

A possible workaround is to generate the HTML and set the column width to a value enough to show all the cell content without wrapping.

To help you achieve this, try generating a workbook in your computer desktop putting text and format similar to the report being exported, then save the workbook as a html file and then take a look at the code generated. Behind all the messy CSS/HTML autogenerated code, you will find some tips to improve the html table. By example, look at this snippet:

```
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 11">
```

With this you are helping MS Excel to identify your HTML file as a Sheet. Now look in the css inside the  element, you will find some custom selectors like `col {mso-width-source:auto;}`. Try playing with its values until you get satisfied with the results, and then incorporate it on the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at that :)